# ¿Cómo emular el do while en Python para pedir dos números y agregarlos a una lista enlazada?

Tags: c#, python

Quisiera poder adaptar este código de C# a Python, sólo que no sé cómo emular lo que es la instrucción do while. Aquí dejaré una parte de mi intento en pasar el código de mi clase Interfaz a Python. Espero me puedan ayudar.

## Código de C#

```
namespace Prog3 {

    public class Interfaz {

        private Lista mLista;

        public Interfaz() {
            mLista = new Lista();
        }

        public void AñadirNumero() {
            double Num1;
            double Num2;
            do {
                Console.Write("Inserte Numero1: ");
                Num1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Inserte Numero2: ");
                Num2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                mLista.Agregar(Num1, Num2);
            } 
            while ((Num1 != (0)) && (Num2 != (0)));
        }

        public Lista GetLista() {
            return mLista;
        }
    }
}
```

## Mi adaptación a Python

```py
class Interfaz:

    Num1 = 0.0
    Num2 = 0.0

    def IngresarDatos(self):
        mLista = Lista():

        while true:
            Num1 = input("Ingresa el numero 1")
            Num2 = input("Ingresa el numero 2")

        if ((Num1 != (0)) && (Num2 != (0))):
          break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahí te dejo varios hints:

- La función `input` devuelve un string, pero tú necesitas que sean números. Para eso, puedes usar la función `float`

```py
num1 = float(input("Ingresa el número 1: "))
```

El programa se va a caer si el usuario pone algo que no es un número, como una letra. Para evitar esto puedes hacer chequeos con if's.

- Asumo que tu clase Lista es hecha por tí o ya te la dan, así que no puedo ayudar en cómo usarla, pero de manera estándar Python ya tiene una clase `list` que puedes usar.

```py
m_lista = list()
... # tu código aquí
m_lista.append(num1)
m_lista.append(num2)
```

- El operador para comparar en Python no es `&&` sino `and`:

```py
if (num1 != 0) and (num2 != 0):
  break
```

- Parece que la indentación está mal. Python es lo que se conoce como whitespace-sensitive, así que tienes que agregar indentación a tu `if` para que se ejecute dentro del `while`.
- La inicialización que haces fuera de la función de `num1` y `num2` no es necesaria en Python. Puedes asignar las variables dentro del `while` sin escribirlas antes porque sólo las usas ahí.

Por último, una cuestión de estilo: Trata de leer sobre PEP8 porque Python tiene un estándar para nombrar variables, etc. [Aquí](https://dev.to/viktorvillalobos/que-es-el-pep-8-y-porque-deberia-implementarlo-54bh) te dejo un pequeño artículo. En resumen, las funciones se escriben como `ingresar_datos`, las variables igual (`m_lista = ...`), y las clases sí se escriben con mayúsculas como lo estás haciendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo ya entendí, también gracias por la información sobre el PEP8 me sera de gran utilidad. Sobre mi clase lista y nodo, yo los hice pero la verdad no se si estén bien, ya que es la primera vez que uso Python.

Comment: @ASJ Un gusto ayudar, recuerda que si la respuesta te pareció útil puedes marcar el check al costado para marcar que responde tu pregunta :)